# Ubuntu 18.04LTS Unity: Terminal window size changes when press "Ctrl" + "+"

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-terminal, fonts

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 with the Unity UI. I want to change my terminal font size by pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>) and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>). So I set my shortcuts from terminal preferences and it works:

[image: screenshot of keyboard shortcuts]

But the terminal window size also increases/decreases, so if I create text smaller the terminal gets smaller and I have to resize it manually. If I dock the terminal with split screen option (by dragging it left or right) it doesn't resize. But this means that every time I need to dock it with split screen option and I want a better solution.

Comment: Try clicking on the border, in the upper left corner of Terminal. If I recall correctly, you will be able to resize text without changing the size of the window, but I'm not where I can check that right now.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. When I click somewhere on the the terminal (on its border, or insight the text window) it still resize both - the font and the window. 
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

> But the terminal window size also increases/decreases

In case of GNOME Terminal, this is the intended behavior.

With docking and split screen, there's an external "force" keeping the window size (as measured in pixels) unchanged. This "force" overrides GNOME Terminal's request on preferred window sizes (to fit entire character cells), so usually you get additional unused space on the right and the bottom.

With "regular" (non docked, non maximized etc.) windows there's no such external "force", so either the window size would still slightly change (in order to always accomodate whole cells, in whichever current font size), or you'd no longer have resize increment geometry hints, you'd end up with continuous resize as done by several other terminal emulators such as `konsole`.

None of these solutions is perfect, each has their pros and cons. GNOME Terminal developers decided to go for maintaining the window size as measured in character cells, that is, a zoom option doesn't effect the app running inside (unless some "external force" forces a different size).